# Odd EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error (I think)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have a `UITableViewCell` that has a couple of `UIImageView`s in it. I have added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to each one, and from them I send a message back to the owning `UIViewController` to push to a new `UIViewController`, passing the `UIImage` along as the data to show in the newly-pushed `UIViewController`.

Here's the code I'm using to do that:

```
- (void)imageViewTappedForImage:(UIImage *)image {
    MSSPictureDetailViewController *vc      = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pictureDetailViewController"];
    vc.image                                = image;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

I get to the last line just fine, but I am consistently getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at that point.

`vc.image` is implemented as a strong property. If I put in a breakpoint, every variable I can think of to check has an actual value.

Does anyone see something I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**
The error message I'm seeing is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here's the backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x33018e, 0x0287b0b2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x77656982)
frame #0: 0x0287b0b2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14
frame #1: 0x016649b7 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 895
frame #2: 0x016718f7 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
frame #3: 0x016724e9 UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
frame #4: 0x017b30d1 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
frame #5: 0x0159a964 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
frame #6: 0x0287d82b libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
frame #7: 0x0078845a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
frame #8: 0x0077c244 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
frame #9: 0x0077c0b0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 26
frame #10: 0x006e27fa QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 294
frame #11: 0x006e3b85 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 393
frame #12: 0x007a15b0 QuartzCore`+[CATransaction flush] + 52
frame #13: 0x015299bb UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 13095
frame #14: 0x02ca377f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #15: 0x02ca310b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
frame #16: 0x02cc01ae CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 910
frame #17: 0x02cbf9d3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
frame #18: 0x02cbf7eb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #19: 0x033d95ee GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #20: 0x033d942b GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #21: 0x0152bf9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
* frame #22: 0x00029d6d IMR`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffee58) + 141 at main.m:16
```

Comment: We are issuing something: post the error message and backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

Is that method `imageViewTappedForImage:` the selector you pass to the gesture recognizer?  That would explain the trouble.  The gr passes *itself* as a param to that method, not the view to which it's attached.  The gr has it's view as a property, so fix this way (if my guess is correct that this is your gr.'s triggered method)...

```
- (void)imageViewTappedForImage:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gr.view;
    MSSPictureDetailViewController *vc      = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pictureDetailViewController"];
    vc.image                                = imageView.image;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: No, that's not how I have it wired up. The method that I showed is in my view controller, called from my table view cell with a valid reference to the image view in that cell. Again, at the line that is causing the crash, all of my variables – including their types – appear to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this one was a doozy!

I ended up trying out a few different ways of calling my `MSSPictureDetailViewController`, all of which failed.

This led me to the fact that my error was unrelated to `UITapGestureRecognizers`, unrelated to which thread was calling my transition, unrelated to `UIImageView` references, etc...

What I finally happened upon was the fact that I had a custom method in my `UIViewController` declared like this:

```
- (IBAction)view;
```

At this point, the answer is pretty obvious to me, but it wasn't at first, so I'm going to state a warning here for posterity:

**DO NOT DECLARE A METHOD NAMED `view` IN A UIVIEWCONTROLLER!!!**

Turns out that each time iOS was trying to access the view property for this `UIViewController` subclass, my empty method was being called instead. Apparently (and understandably), this confused the system and it didn't know what to put on-screen, since it never got access to the `UIView` object it was expecting.

Anyway, changing

```
- (IBAction)view
```

to

```
- (IBAction)viewPicture
```

solved everything.

I'm a bit surprised, however, that overriding

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *view
```

with

```
- (IBAction)view
```

(which changes the return type from `UIView` to `void`) didn't throw a compiler error (or at least a warning).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to track down an EXC_BAD_ACCESS is to enable Zombie Objects from the edit scheme menu. Once you have enabled it, you should profile your application using the Zombie instrument. Now reproduce your bug and look at the allocation panel. Whenever a zombie is detected a red mark will show up there, describing the location of the zombie and giving you useful hints on who is the responsible of it.

Now, you should really extend your question adding more details, with the ones you provided I doubt we can help more than this.

Comment: While I agree that this is the standard way to solve an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and track down zombies, my particular case had nothing to do with that. You didn't read my answer, which I posted 12 hours before yours. Please see it to understand the actual issue in this case.

Comment: Wow, i can swear that the answer you gave wasn't showing when I replied, probably a cache issue. Anyway happy you found what the issue was